# extract data from nested xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am newbie using `xpath`,
I wanna extract every single title, body, link , release date from [this link](http://thehackernews.com/search/label/mobile%20hacking)

everthing seems okay, but no on body, how to extract every single body on nested xPath, thanks before :)

here my source

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from thehack.items import ThehackItem
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "thehack"
    allowed_domains = ["thehackernews.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://thehackernews.com/search/label/mobile%20hacking"]
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath('//article[@class="post item module"]')
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = ThehackItem()
            item['title'] = titles.select('span/h2/a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = titles.select('span/h2/a/@href').extract()
        item['body'] = titles.select('span/div/div/div/div/a/div/text()').extract()
        item['date'] = titles.select('span/div/span/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

anybody can fix about body blok? only on body...
thanks before mate
here the picture of inspection elements from the website
[image]

Comment: What do you need to fix for `'body'`? what are you getting? what are you expecting?

Comment: i want to get the main content about the article, what article discussioning...
but i get nothing mate

Comment: can you help me paul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you where struggling with the selectors, right? I think you should check the documentation for [selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html), there's a lot of good information there. In this particular example, using the css selectors, I think it would be something like:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "thehack"
    allowed_domains = ["thehackernews.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://thehackernews.com/search/label/mobile%20hacking"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for article in response.css('article.post'):
            item = ThehackItem()
            item['title'] = article.css('.post-title>a::text').extract_first()
            item['link'] = article.css('.post-title>a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            item['body'] = ''. join(article.css('[id^=summary] *::text').extract()).strip()
            item['date'] = article.css('[itemprop="datePublished"]::attr(content)').extract_first()
            yield item
```

It would be a good exercise for you to change them to xpath selectors and maybe also check about [ItemLoaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html), together are very useful.

Comment: you you help me to get the body content of the paragprah mate?